# Xamarin app has stopped

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, spinner

I have implemented a project in Xamarin.On running it on emulator and as well as on device, it shows that Unfortunately, App has stopped.

I'm newbie to xamarin and I'm clueless with this issue.
I've resolved all the errors and warnings but it shows like that only.

My device catlog is as follows:
[image]

custom spinner.cs

```
namespace App1.Assets.Ccode.Cspinner
{


    class CustomSpinner : BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context c;
        private JavaList<CountryName> countries;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CustomSpinner(Context c, JavaList<CountryName> countries)
        {
            this.c = c;
            this.countries = countries;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return countries.Get(position);
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (inflater == null)
            {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            }

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.country_list, parent, false);
            }

            TextView nameTxt = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameTxt);
            ImageView img = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.India);

            //BIND
            nameTxt.Text = countries[position].Name;
            img.SetImageResource(countries[position].Image);


            return convertView;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return countries.Size();
            }
        }

    }
  }
  }
```

Main activiy

```
[Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private Spinner sp;
    private CustomSpinner adapter;
    private JavaList<CountryName> countries;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        sp = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.country);
        countries = CountriesList.GetCountrys();
        adapter = new CustomSpinner(this, countries);

        sp.Adapter = (ISpinnerAdapter)adapter;
        sp.ItemSelected += sp_ItemSelected;
    }

    void sp_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, countries[e.Position].Name, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="App1.App1" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:label="App1"></application>
</manifest>
```

Please save my day and help me to run it on device.

Thank you

Comment: What is the target framework?

Comment: @Mohammed Dastagir you have **still not updated** anything related to `file`

Comment: @Mrinmoy Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a **NullPointerException**

```
file.getAbsolutePath();
```

The `error` is saying `file` objecy is **null**

This is the exact error:-
[image: click to see image]

Comment: How can I help dear without code.  The file object is null on which you are trying to use getAbsolutePath(). So check why file is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

With very few background details in your question or without your actual code I can suggest you the following:

1. Edit your `.csproj`. If `<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>` in file, try setting it to `False`like `<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>False</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>`. Clean everything and rebuild, reinstall the app.
2. Go to `AndroidManifest.xml` and set 'Install location' to `internalOnly`.
3. Try downgrading `Target Framework`.

P.S: The above are 3 individually different suggestions not 3 different steps of the same suggestion.
The above suggestions usually work but again you have not mentioned much of the details in the question.